# Azure Data Explorer Limits

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Are there known limits for Azure Data Explorer? I am looking for limits on

- Number of databases that can be created
- Number of tables a database

The only limits document I found is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/concepts/querylimits

Would be helpful to know these limits.

Comment: Update: Found the answer to the number of tables ... Maximum limit of tables per database is 10,000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[ reply is accurate as of 2020-02-04 ]*

Number of databases in a cluster: 10,000

Number of tables in a database: 10,000

Comment: Thx @Yoni L. Would you happen to know the limit on clusters?

Comment: if you mean: number of clusters per subscription per region -> that's included here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#azure-data-explorer-limits